# У меня проблема с выставлением диапазона между каждым тиком, где тик - это дата

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas

У меня есть таблица df, в которой timestamp - это дата, а cnt - это количество арендованных велосипедов. Когда я хочу построить граф, в котором показано количество арендованных велосипедов в определенный год/месяц/день, то выдается ошибка

> "None of [Index(['2015-01-04 00:00:00', '2015-01-04 01:00:00',
> '2015-01-04 02:00:00',\n       '2015-01-04 03:00:00', '2015-01-04
> 04:00:00', '2015-01-04 05:00:00',\n       '2015-01-04 06:00:00',
> '2015-01-04 07:00:00', '2015-01-04 08:00:00',\n       '2015-01-04
> 09:00:00',\n       ...\n       '2017-01-03 14:00:00', '2017-01-03
> 15:00:00', '2017-01-03 16:00:00',\n       '2017-01-03 17:00:00',
> '2017-01-03 18:00:00', '2017-01-03 19:00:00',\n       '2017-01-03
> 20:00:00', '2017-01-03 21:00:00', '2017-01-03 22:00:00',\n
> '2017-01-03 23:00:00'],\n      dtype='object', length=17414)] are in
> the [columns]"

При этом мне нужно сделать так, чтобы на оси x были не все даты, а даты 2015/2016/2017 года отдельно(3 разных таблиц) и сделать так, чтобы диапазоном между каждым тиком был 1 месяц.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\bossd\OneDrive\Документы\datarn.csv")

x = df['timestamp']
y = df['cnt']
ax2 = df.plot.scatter(x,y, x_compat = True)
```

[image: Образец данных]

Comment: Образец данных совсем бы не помешал

Comment: Приложил скриншот

Comment: Вам бы было удобно перебивать данные из скриншота?

Comment: а как отправить файл?

Comment: Один из вариантов - [таблица](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/194/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-stackoverflow)

Comment: а как им поделиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе `.plot.scatter(x, y, x_compat = True)` как первые 2 аргумента ожидаются **не** серии (как сделали вы), а просто **имена столбцов**. *Вот ваша ошибка!*
(Об этом и говорит сообщение об ошибке, которое вы получили.)

Итак, я думаю, что вы вместо

```
x = df['timestamp']
y = df['cnt']
ax2 = df.plot.scatter(x,y, x_compat = True)
```

хотели

```
ax2 = df.plot.scatter('timestamp', 'cnt', x_compat = True)
```

Comment: result_str_contains был сделан отдельно для подсчета cnt в каждом году(другая цель)

Comment: @krmbla, так что вы показали эту строку в вашем вопросе, только чтобы обмануть нас. ;-)

Comment: прошу прощения, удалил

Comment: Прошу прощения, приспособил тому мой ответ. ;-)

Comment: из-за массива данных очень долго рисует график :-(, скорее нужно сначала отредактировать так, чтобы можно было рисовать ось x  по годам

Comment: @krmbla, но рисует, значит, работает, и мой ответ был для вас полезным. Потому вы можете принять его (клик на галочку налево от него).

Comment: Понял, спасибо!